# Are there any Music XML sites on SE or Stack Overflow where I can ask questions about the code?

Tags: discussion, recommendations

I want to ask a question either on here or on a Music XML forum because I'm trying to figure out how Finale made a flute part pitch bend in MIDI, and yet, upon opening the XML in notepad, I can't see anything that tells me that there was a pitch bend. No glissando, no portamento, nothing.

What site might be appropriate for this question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this is an appropriate stack for your question. To me, it falls under "usage of specific music software or hardware", which is explicitly on-topic.